# Add words together to form all possible combinations

Tags: python, iteration, python-itertools

So I have recently picked up python and I am trying to get all the different combinations of multiple words. I have been looking at itertools, but have failed to achieve my desired result. It is easier explained with a practical example. This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
somestring = "cat, cake, apples"
result = itertools magik
print result

>>> catcake, catapples, cakecat, cakeapples, applescat, applescake
```

So far this is the closest I have gotten to achieving this, but it does not return every iteration possible:

```
from itertools import combinations
print ["".join(a) for a in combinations(["cat", "cake", "apples"], 2)]

>>> ['catcake', 'catapples', 'cakeapples']
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `permutations` instead of combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually looking for [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) not [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> print(["".join(a) for a in permutations(["cat", "cake", "apples"], 2)])
['catcake', 'catapples', 'cakecat', 'cakeapples', 'applescat', 'applescake']
```

Comment: I actually think I was just an inch from this answer a few minutes ago. Thank you a lot, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
from itertools import permutations
print ["".join(a) for a in permutations(["cat", "cake", "apples"], 2)]
#['catcake', 'catapples', 'cakecat', 'cakeapples', 'applescat', 'applescake']
```

This happens because in `combinations` order doesn't matters, in `permutations` do matter, e.g.:

```
'(cat,cake)' == '(cake, cat)' # Combinations
'(cat,cake)' != '(cake, cat)' # Permutations
```